# Storing file-paths in Core-Data and guaranteeing Consistency

Tags: macos, core-data

I am storing local file paths in Core-Data for files that can be added, moved and deleted. Every file move operation therefore requires a Core-Data write. This obviously is neither Atomic nor guarantees Consistency - the user could, for example, force-quit at any point.

Is there an common way to handle this? I'm guessing this is a problem that has arisen before…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you cannot rely on bookmark data you could use some kind of transactional approach:

1. Duplicate the managed object that refers to your file and update it's file name.
2. Save the managed object context
3. Rename the file
4. Delete the original managed object.
5. Save the managed object context again.

In the worst case the user will force quit anywhere in between and you will have to recover from that situation. But this is easy, just delete the managed object whose file is missing and your data is consistent again.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the kind of thing i felt i should know how todo. I'm still surprised that it is often said "Don't store file blobs in the database, store the paths" but then not much advice follows on the difficulties this causes.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Bookmark Data for that file from the NSURL to that file and save that instand. This way the user can move the file even while your app is not running and you still can get to that file after the app is launched again.

If you want to use app sandboxing (because you want to sell your app on the App Store for example) you have to store the bookmark data anyways, because otherwise you won't be able to get access to those files again, if they are not stored in your application sandbox.

Comment: Interesting approach. I know i didn't specify in the question but i could really do with an approach that would work on iOS as well.

Comment: All right, I have another idea for that case. I'll add another answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading about bookmarks now and i appreciate you bringing them to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

You should, each time you write in Core-Data, use the saveContext method

```
app = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[app saveContext];
```

Comment: Thanks @moxy, the problem is what happens, for example, if i move a file AND THEN the user forces the app to quit before [app saveContext] is called

Comment: @hooleyhoop : when your application is launched you should verify the integrity of your filepaths (do the files still exists ? Do I have files that shouldn't be there then recreate the path).

Comment: and if i find there is an inconsistency?

Comment: Then act accordingly : there is a file, recreate the path in your app, there is no file but you have a path, delete the path. Maybe you could use some kind of "garbage"/"history" entity for moving and delete. This could help to recreate a path or the data linked to it for example. Now i don't know your app so it's hard to answer what is the best solution in your case (is there datas stored linked to it or just paths for example, is it better to just delete the path or inform the user, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. The first i would know is that i have path in the database that isn't valid. Is your suggestion to validate every Core-Data entity on startup, and if an invalid entity is found cross-check each file against each entity to find one that isn't represented, and assume that is the missing one?

Comment: _Is your suggestion to validate every Core-Data entity on startup_ Yes, I would validate every entity filepath, and retrieve the filepath  of everyfile under your root document directory (where you've gathered all files) so you'll be able to check if some are missing or placed anywhere else or if you've got files without the link in your app. about assuming it's the missing one, it should have the same document name. Not sure if i'm clear but it's a two way check to ensure everything is fine.